# How to re write pandas for loop computation with list comprehension or np.where / np.select

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
#BOH qty * capacity to get EQ
for i in final_merge2['FLAG']:
    if i =='BOH':
        for j in final_merge2['Plan_ID']:
            if j =='JUL':
                final_merge2['EQ202207'] = (final_merge2['Qty202207']*final_merge2['Capacity'])/1000000
```

This logic is taking 30 mins because of data size

Tried this logic but didnt work

```
conditions  = [(final_merge2['FLAG'] == 'BOH') & (final_merge2['Plan_ID'] =='JUL')]
choices     = [(final_merge2['Qty202207']*final_merge2['Capacity'])/1000000]
final_merge2["EQ202207"] = np.select(conditions, , default=final_merge2["EQ202207"])
```

also this

```
final_merge2["EQ202207"]=((final_merge2['Qty202207']*final_merge2['Capacity'])/1000000).where(final_merge2.FLAG == 'BOH',(.where(final_merge2.Plan_ID=='JUL')))
```

But I didnt get the working solution.

How to re write pandas for loop computation with list comprehension or `np.where  / np.select`

I want to multiply two columns  & divide by `100000` if two columns has the values (`final_merge2['FLAG'] =='BOH &final_merge2['Plan_ID']=='JUL`)

```
final_merge2['Qty202207']*final_merge2['Capacity'])/1000000
```

Comment: `but the output is wrong` - can you be more specific? Seems correct for me.

Comment: Output is wrong meant the second logic just gave FALSE as output in the data frame
& other logic not executing, syntax error

Comment: Can you try `final_merge2["EQ202207"] = np.where((final_merge2['FLAG'] == 'BOH') & (final_merge2['Plan_ID'] =='JUL'),  (final_merge2['Qty202207']*final_merge2['Capacity'])/1000000, final_merge2["EQ202207"])`

Comment: there is typo, missing `choices`, need `final_merge2["EQ202207"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=final_merge2["EQ202207"])`